# Mysqli bind - unknown number of parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to bind unknown number of parameters with Mysqli? For example, following my code:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE";
if(isset($_POST['r1']))
  $query = $query." id = '$_POST['r1']'";
if(isset($_POST['r2']))
  $query = $query." AND par2 = '$_POST['r2']'";
$e = mysqli_prepare($conf, $query);
?>
```

How to do bind of parameters?

Comment: You should never use `isset`. Use `!empty` instead.

Comment: @DevlshOne in this case `isset` is the right choice. Suppose one of these `$_POST` variables is 0? It's a legitimate value, but `empty()` will return the wrong value for this purpose.

Comment: Using `empty` to check for form data is usually a bad choice. `isset`  implies both a declared and defined variable and since form data is of type  string, where empty string is still considered to define a variable, `isset` is the right choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statements probably aren't the best way to do this. You can assemble a query just as you are doing, as long as you make sure that you escape any user input. For example:

```
<?php

// assuming $db is a mysqli object

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE";
if(isset($_POST['r1']))
  $query = $query."id = '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['r1'])."'";
if(isset($_POST['r2']))
  $query = $query." AND par2 = '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['r2'])."'";

$result = $db->query($query);
?>
```

Don't forget to add any required error checking.

Comment: The obsessive zeal with which prepared statements are trumpeted on this site as _the_ way to defend against SQL Injection ignores the many edge cases where prepared statements are unnecessary, clumsy or impossible to use. This is one. Provided you exercise sufficient care with escaping your inputs there's no reason why a simple query shouldn't be perfectly safe.

Comment: @user3022323 With PDO, you *can* use prepared statements. Is switching to PDO an option for you?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel You can use prepared statements with `mysqli` too. You'd have to construct your statement piece by piece before preparing it, then bind your parameters as you would with PDO. The question is, why bother? While constructing a template query one can construct the final query just as easily. This falls under 'clumsy' in my comment above.

Comment: I know you can use prepared statements with MySQLi, but with PDO you can use *named parameters*, which are what you need when you want to build query strings dynamically.